# mySQL Ranks Ties To Next Higher Number

Tags: mysql

Rank with Ties works correctly except that the first record is always missing, no matter how it's fetched. Trying to rank **low to high.**

```
SELECT x.*, 
COUNT(*) AS myRank 
FROM myTablename x 
JOIN myTablename y 
ON x.number > y.number 
GROUP BY id  
ORDER BY myRank
```

PLEASED TO SAY, AFTER A LONG BATTLE, **THE FOLLOWING REVISION WORKS AS INTENDED!**

```
SELECT x.*, 
Count(y.id)+1 AS myRank
FROM myTablename x 
LEFT JOIN myTablename y 
ON (x.number > y.number) 
GROUP BY x.id 
ORDER BY myRank
```

Result:

```
ID  #   Rank
A  -50  1
B  -40  2
C  -40  2
D  -30  4
E  -30  4
```

Adding "=" to... **ON x.number >= y.number** ...gets ranking with ties right, except that the tied records rank to the next higher number.

```
ID  #   Rank
A  -50  1
B  -40  3
C  -40  3
D  -30  5
E  -30  5
```

Ranking High-to-low with **ON x.number <= y.number** does the same thing.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET... and what if there is no y < x !?!?!

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean. Tried to state an example, as simply as possible.

Comment: If you're likely to be tagging further questions under 'mysql' on SO, then it might be an idea to acquaint yourself with 'what I mean' ! ;-)

Comment: And who upvotes this stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version without a self-join but rather using variables. It's most likely also faster:

```
select id, points, rank from (
select
t.*,
@rownum := @rownum + 1,
@rank := if(@prev_points = points, @rank, @rownum) as rank,
@prev_points := points
from
test t,
(select @rank:=0, @rownum:=0, @prev_points) var_init
order by points desc
)sq
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ede2/3/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for that approach. As a newcomer, unaware of sqlfiddle and thanks again for that link. Tested there and working as wanted. However, my code gets consecutive rank number, without ties. Maybe because I'm CASTing (varchar) points using "points+0"

Comment: Why are you casting? Or better asked, why are you storing your points as varchar anyway? You can change your table design afterwards with `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name column_name_again INT;` But that might not be your problem. Create a sqlfiddle with your table structure and some sample data and I'll have a look.

Comment: For another area, an INT produced a 0 and I needed to display a "blank." Will give that consideration. However, surprised and frustrated that my simple JOINS are so close to working.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no clue about PHP, but from MySQL side I don't see why it shouldn't work. Maybe the fetching in PHP really is the problem.